# How do I get my graphics card to work?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, 20.04

I'm brand new to Ubuntu 20.04 and I have just installed it on my old PC with the plan of turning it into a home media center, problem is when I try to do anything it freezes, see this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234358/how-do-i-stop-ubuntu-from-freezing-when-i-click-on-almost-anything?noredirect=1#comment2077900_1234358).

After doing some research and messing around, the problem is probably because of the graphics drivers. My only experience with installing new ones is when you download software that does it for you, no good here on Windows.

So, I have a AMD Radeon HD 6950 that I would like to use and I downloaded the .deb file from AMD, I have so far tried to follow [this guide](https://drivers.amd.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf):

When I reach page 10 (point 5) I hit a snag, it's talking about packages and I don't know what they are or where to get them, any help to get me started would be good, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any private driver for your Radeon (or Intel), especially for this one.
Simply install the last open-source drivers from Oibaf Repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

And update your system

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks very much for replying/helping, I ran those commands and it downloaded/updated, my hopes shot up as everything seems to work for about 5 mins, I made it to a website, downloaded a graphics card stress test (MSI Kombustor) and opened it... and it froze again :'(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not a problem regarding your Driver, but anyway make sure you have the correct ones.

First of all uninstall completely the Private (fglrx) drivers (if installed with dpkg):

```
sudo dpkg –P fglrx fglx-core fglrx-dev fglrx-amdcccle
```

And Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Once rebooted, check what driver you are using.
Install mesa-utils

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

and run the following command:

```
glxinfo -B
```

And copy what says the Output.